# OpenCV with C++ won't compile

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I've been following [this](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2013/06/load-display-image.html) tutorial on using OpenCV with C++, and used the following code to read an image.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 Mat img = imread("map.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); //read the image data in the file "MyPic.JPG" and store it in 'img'

 if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
 {
      cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
      //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
      return -1;
 }

 namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
 imshow("MyWindow", img); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

 waitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress

 destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

 return 0;
}
```

I created a simple .cpp file in vi and tried to compile it using
g++ -o test test.cpp.

I checked and I have OpenCV in /usr/bin.
These are the errors I am getting on compile:

```
error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
error: ‘cv’ is not a namespace-name
error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
In function ‘int main()’:
error: ‘Mat’ was not declared in this scope
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘img’
error: ‘img’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘namedWindow’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘img’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘imshow’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘waitKey’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘destroyWindow’ was not declared in this scope
```

I am using RHEL 6.
What can I do to fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Where is opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp in relation to test.cpp?  Your compiler is complaining that it can't find that file, so that needs to be fixed first.

Comment: @RomSteady I copied that from the tutorial, so I assumed it was standard syntax. In /usr/bin, I have the files opencv_createsamples, opencv_haartraining, opencv_performance, and opencv_traincascade. Should I replace opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp with one of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem using CentOS 7 (pretty much the same OS as you)

The ONLY way I was able to get it to compile was using [these](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) instruction for CMake in the OpenCV documentation.

But basically...

1) Make your program source in an empty folder.

2) Make a CMakeLists.txt file in that same folder with these lines...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

note: this part is has a few more lines if you need extra flags but that's a different topic...

3) Then run these bash commands...

```
$cd <DisplayImage_directory>
$cmake .
$make
```

If this doesn't work then OpenCV has two more methods in their documentation for how to do this.

Comment: Good suggestion, but to make this answer a lasting one, summarize the contents of the link so there is some hope of future readers recreating the steps should the link rot.

Comment: I followed these instructions and it unfortunately didn't work. Thank you for the link!